# Winform not visible while debugging

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have an application that manipulates with some files in certain matter and have progressbar and textbox. When I debug (VS2010), the app window is not visible, but the app does all the work that it suppose to. If I wanted to create invisible winform application I would probably have to bust my brains out to do so. Now I have one I don't want. How about that? Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Most likely, you are "doing the work" in the form initialization, on the same thread as the GUI. The form will appear when the work is done, unless the application exits automatically.

Comment: @John Willemse That is exactely what I did. Can I remove all the work from initialization in single block?

Comment: You should preferably start the work after user interaction, e.g. a button click. Then you can put the "work" code in a method that you can call. The method should then do the work in a separate thread, so that the progressbar can be updated as needed. Research `BackGroundWorker` class for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP is performing work in the form's initialization phase. During that phase, the form is not yet shown and will not be shown untill all the work is done.

The solution is to move the work code from the form's initialize method to a separate method, that is called only *after* the form is shown. This method should perform the work on a separate thread to ensure the GUI stays repsonsive, the process can be cancelled and reports back to update the progress bar.